# What could be the problem on why the computation in the getCurrentLocation returns 0.0000 or -0.0000?

Tags: flutter, dart, accelerometer

At debug it works at first but after some restart or after testing the values will be 0.0000, -0.0000 where in fact there is new and previous data for accelerometer.

void getCurrentLocation() async {
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();

```
if (status.isGranted) {
  _positionStreamSubscription?.cancel(); // Cancel any existing subscription

  _positionStreamSubscription = location.Location().onLocationChanged.listen((position) {
    if (!mounted) return;

    // Update the UI with the current location data
    setState(() {
      initialCameraPosition = LatLngWithAltitude(
        latitude: position.latitude!,
        longitude: position.longitude!,
        altitude: position.altitude!,
      );

      speed = position.speed! * 3.6;

      if (speed < 1.0) {
        speed = 0.0;
      }

      // Print current speed and location information
      print('Speed: $speed km/h');
      print('Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}');

      // Store previous accelerometer data for comparison
      previousAccelerometerY = newAccelerometerY;
      previousAccelerometerTimestamp = DateTime.now();

      // Listen to accelerometer events
      _accelerometerSubscription ??= accelerometerEvents.listen((accelerometerEvent) {
        if (previousAccelerometerY != null && previousAccelerometerTimestamp != null) {
          DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
          double deltaTime = currentTime.difference(previousAccelerometerTimestamp!).inMilliseconds / 1000.0;

          // Apply low-pass filter to accelerometer data
          newAccelerometerY = applyLowPassFilter(accelerometerEvent.y, previousAccelerometerY!, 0.5);
          newAccelerometerY = applyLowPassFilter(accelerometerEvent.y, previousAccelerometerY!, 0.5);

          // Calculate altitude change in inches
          double altitudeChangeInMeters = 0.5 * (newAccelerometerY - previousAccelerometerY!) * deltaTime * deltaTime;
          double altitudeChangeInInches = altitudeChangeInMeters * 39.3701;

          // Update the changeInYValue with calculated altitude change
          changeInYValue = altitudeChangeInInches;

          // Print accelerometer data and altitude change information
          print('New Accelerometer Value while running: ${newAccelerometerY.toStringAsFixed(14)} inches');
          print('Previous Accelerometer Y: ${previousAccelerometerY!.toStringAsFixed(14)} inches');
          print('Altitude Change in Inches: ${changeInYValue.toStringAsFixed(14)} inches');
        }

        // Update previous accelerometer data
        previousAccelerometerY = newAccelerometerY;
        previousAccelerometerTimestamp = DateTime.now();
      });

      // If map controller is available and autoCameraZoomEnabled, update zoom level
      if (_mapController != null && autoCameraZoomEnabled) {
        double newZoom = calculateZoomLevel(speed);

        _mapController?.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(
                position.latitude!,
                position.longitude!,
              ),
              zoom: newZoom,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      // Store previous position for future reference
      previousPosition = position;
    });
  });
} else if (status.isDenied) {
  _showPermissionDialog();
}
```

}

sample output, which is correct
[image: Correct output]

sample output, which is incorrect
[image: incorrect output]

the value of the accelerometer becomes smaller.